# How to test the null hypothesis that two linear regression lines have the same Y value for a particular X value?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, ancova

I am using ancova to test if two linear regression models are the same and it works great. I am following this tutorial: http://www.biostathandbook.com/ancova.html and I apply it in R with this tutorial  http://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/e_04.html.
Now I am interested in a similar problem, where I want to test if two regression models have the same value y at a given x.

The anther of the tutorial hints to the solution of this problem: "If the slopes are different, there are techniques for testing the null hypothesis that the regression lines have the same Y value for a particular X value, but they're not used very often and I won't consider them here." at "how the test works" in the first link.

Unfortunately he does not mention the name of the test nor does he give another hint where to look for the technique. So, does anyone know the name of the test or a link to a tutorial for this?

Comment: This might go unanswered because the Q is a bit unclear. If you have multiple regressors in both models, all equal? What is the difference between the two models? Two different samles, all else equal? ... Please add some details and context!